# How to Insert View in Superview's View? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, subview, superview, uiview-hierarchy

I have the line of code below... How would I modify it to insert the subview in the superview's view named 'foo'?

```
[[self superview] addSubview:copy3];
```

Comment: If you are using storyboard, and superview and your view are in the same view controller's view, you can just define an outlet and refer to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "named foo"?  Views don't have a name property, do you have an ivar named foo?

Comment: I'm thinking the code would look something like this" [[self superview].foo addSubview:copy3];

Comment: Bad approach. Let view controller or at least superview manage where to insert your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more than 1 ways of doing this -

1.have an `IBOutlet` reference in your code. This is created from xcode Interface builder. Once you have this then it fairly straight forward -

```
[iboutlet_foo_object addSubview:copy3];
```

2.`tag` the view that you are interested in. Again tagging a view can be done from xcode Interface builder or from code. After that -

```
Foo *fooObj = [[self superview] viewWithTag:tagInt];
[fooObj addSubview:copy3];
```

3.Finally you can iterate through all the views in your superview & see which one is of type `Foo` -

```
NSArray *subviews = [[self superview] subviews];
for(UIView *v in subviews)
{
    if(v isKindOfClass:[Foo class])
    {
        [v addSubview:copy3];
        break;
    }
}
```

hope these methods help you...

Comment: Hmm... It's not recognizing the view in the other view controller using your methods.

Comment: you need to have a reference to it in your new viewController. First create an empty instance of `foo` class. Then try to copy reference of `foo` from your oldViewController to your newViewController.

Comment: foo isn't a class... It's a uiview declared in the parent view

Answer (score 1):

First make myView into a property of the superview 
Then use

```
[[[self superview] myView] addSubview:mySubview];
```

Comment: It says instance method not found... Any idea why? EDIT: it looks like the other guy's answer is working.

Comment: ok :), you should have made myView int an @property in the view super view class

Comment: I had added myView as an @property. What do you mean myView int?

Comment: sorry a type, did you @ synthesize it?

Answer (score 1):

First tag the view myView with a unique number:

```
myView.tag = 0x1234;
```

Then you can find it using viewWithTag:

```
[[[self superview] viewWithTag:0x1234] addSubview:mySubview];
```

Comment: Okay, so it no longer ads the subview to the view it was... but its not adding it at all now. Probably because it cant find a view with the tag I set even though I set the tag in the superview. Any idea why its not finding it?

Answer (score 0):

You might just actually add it to 'view' instead of 'superview'.

```
[[self view] addSubview:mySubview];
```

It works just fine for me, whenever I add subviews to my parent view.
Let me know if something went wrong.