# How do I Insert View in Superview's View? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Insert View in Superview's View? (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942681/how-to-insert-view-in-superviews-view-ios)

I have the line of code below... How would I modify it to insert the subview "mySubview" in a UIView named "myView" that is found in the superview?

```
[[self superview] addSubview:mySubview];
```